# run curl command on bootup

Tags: ubuntu, curl

im working on getting my roku tv to turn on when the pc boots up for a gaming console. i can get this comnad to run and works great manually. but need it to run when the pc boots up and thats the only time. just once. Total ubuntu newbie here. so if you could kind give me the walk thru version lol. thank you to whoever fixes my 5 day headache!

here is the command

```
curl -d '' http://192.168.1.137:8060/keypress/PowerOn
```

just need it to run on bootup!

Comment: This kind of basic question has been answered many times on this site (and others). Please search for existing solutions before creating a new question. (in your case search for something like "ubuntu/linux run script on startup").

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a systemd unit.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/wakeTV.service
```

Paste this into the file

```
[Unit]
Description=Wake TV on boot
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl http://192.168.1.137:8060/keypress/PowerOn

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, enable this unit at startup

```
$ sudo systemctl enable wakeTV.service
```

Now, it should run at boot. To diagnose errors, use `systemctl status wakeTV`

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.137 port 8060: No route to host
Jan 26 05:53:47 gbox systemd[1]: wakeTV.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=7/NOTRUNNING
Jan 26 05:53:47 gbox systemd[1]: wakeTV.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: is it possible the wireless card isnt connected when this service is ran?

Answer (score 0):

A cron job to run the command at boot.

A command:

```
@reboot command arg1 arg2 ... argn
```

A script:

```
@reboot script.sh
```

In your case run `crontab -e` then add the following line:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/curl -d '' http://192.168.1.137:8060/keypress/PowerOn
```

Help Ubuntu: [CronHowto-Crontab Lines](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Crontab_Lines)

Comment: can you give me a little more of a walk thru version? im sorry im totally new to ubuntu but im learning alot and love it

Comment: @GusRodriguez Welcome, I have added a link to ubuntu wiki that explain cron and how to use it with examples.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with Raspberry Pi, trying to make a service that reports via web upon boot. For me things like

> ```
> Wants=network-online.target
> After=network-online.target NetworkManager.service network.target systemd-networkd.service
> ```

did nothing. Crontab also fails, of course. At least if you're on wifi then for certain. This is what I ended up using with actual success:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service name


[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s
ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl parameters for curl


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```